# How to add two string array members into one string variable

Tags: java, arrays, string

I've been trying to figure out how to add an extra string array member to a string variable with no luck. Here is the code.

```
 myDirString = myDirString.trim();
    String[] myDirStringParts = myDirString.split(" +");

    MySize = myDirStringParts[0];
    MyNum =  myDirStringParts[1];
    Total =  myDirStringParts[2];
    MyName = myDirStringParts[3];
```

Basically I want `myDirStringParts[2];` to also be included into `MyName`.

Comment: if you are getting an out of bounds error it means the split isn't producing 4 parts, which means there aren't 4 parts separated by " +", perhaps you should show the value of myDirString

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MyName = myDirStringParts[3] + myDirStringParts[2];
```

will work.

Comment: well the problem is that all the strings im passing into MyDirectory are the same except the last one. The last one is short by 1 array. Hence the out of bounds, but I'm supposed to pass the third array member from the last string to `MyName`. It's really tricky.

Comment: 2365106332   1140  SUB-TOTAL: E:\WIS26\MYSQL

Comment: 91535864328  301122  TOTAL

Comment: So like above, the last string would be 4th one, and I want "TOTAL" to be `MyName` as well.

Comment: if (myDirStringParts.length == 4) MyName = myDirStringParts[3]; else MyName = myDirStringParts[2];

Comment: well I found a workaround, I just added an extra character to the string. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
MyName = myDirStringParts[3] + myDirStringParts[2];
```

should do the trick.

However, i notice a few things about your code that i would like to point out:

1. Declare the variables `MyName`, `Total`, `MyNum`, `MySize`.
2. Make sure that `myDirStringParts` contains atleast 3 elements after the `split(" +")` call.

You can do this by the following code snippet:

```
if(myDirStringParts.length >= 4) {  
    MySize = myDirStringParts[0];
    MyNum = myDirStringParts[1];
    Total = myDirStringParts[2];
    MyName = myDirStringParts[3] + myDirStringParts[2];
}  else {  
    // print out an error message.  
    System.err.println("myDirString does not contain all the required data!");  
}
```

Comment: It should be at least 4, since 3 is the 4th element, 0-indexed.